# Explanation of the two percentage numbers in tensorflow's profiler?

Tags: tensorflow, profiling

I am using [the profiler tool](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/core/profiler) provided by tensorflow. Here is one snapshot of the profiling results:
[image]

My question: what's the meaning of the two percentage numbers after the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first number is the percentage of the total memory used/time spent in the function while the second one is the percentage of the memory used/time spent in the function that is **not** allocated/spent in the **inner** functions. Often these are called inclusive (including the functions in the function) and exclusive (excluding the functions in the function) profilings.

---

I'll explain this for timings but it works the same for memory profiling.

This is because profilers just measure how long each function call takes. For example if you have:

```
def func1():
    # something
    func2()
    # something

def func2():
    # something
```

And let's assume that the profiler for a `func1()` call measures 1000ms are spent in `func1` and `750ms` are spent in `func2` then the numbers would be:

```
func1    100%    25%
func2     75%
```

Because 100% of the time is spent in `func1` - but only 25% ((1000ms-750ms)/1000ms) of the time is spent in `func1` that **isn't** spent in `func2`. Likewise 75% (750ms/1000ms) is spent in total in `func2`. In this example the second number for `func2` would also be 75% because I didn't include any code there but if there were other functions inside then the same math would be applied. So to not confuse I didn't include it there.

To make it more interesting and include another example assume you have:

```
def func1():
    # something
    func2()
    # something
    func3()
    # something

def func2():
    # something

def func3():
    # something
```

And the profiler measures 1000 ms in `func1`, 200ms in `func2` and 500 ms in `func3` the table would look like this:

```
func1   100% (1000 / 1000)    30%  ((1000 - 200 - 500) / 1000)
func2    20% ( 200 / 1000)
func3    50% ( 500 / 1000)
```